# R Shiny - Can't Display Prerendered Image

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a prerendered image in the images folder of the Shiny app folder.  I'm trying to get the app to render the image EXG.jpeg, but only the alt text shows up.  What's going wrong?

\Server File

```
setwd('C:/Users/E0265074/Documents/PrelimShiny/')

  function(input, output) {output$Option1 = renderUI({

  if (input$study == 'EX') {

    selectInput('differ', label='Patient ID', choices = c('013412-826-001-002','013412-840-001-001','013412-840-001-002','013412-840-001-003','013412-840-001-004'))

  }

})

output$plot <- renderImage({
      return(list(
        src = "./images/EXG.jpeg",
        contentType = "image/jpeg",
        alt = "Face"
      ))
    })

})
```

\UI File

```
library(shiny) 


shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel('Biomarker Comparison'),

  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(

    tabsetPanel(type = c('tabs'), 

                tabPanel('Plot 1 Options', selectInput('study', label = 'Study Type', choices = c('EX')), 
                         uiOutput('Option1'), 
                         uiOutput('Option2'), 
                         uiOutput('Option3')

                ),

                tabPanel('Plot 2 Options', selectInput('studya', label = 'Study Type', choices = c('EX')), 
                         uiOutput('Option1a'), 
                         uiOutput('Option2a'), 
                         uiOutput('Option3a')
                )

    ), 

  ),


  mainPanel(imageOutput('img1')
  )




  )

))
```

Comment: Any particular reason you tagged this for `shiny-server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't using the correct `imageOutput` label. `img1` is wrong, you needed `plot` because that is how the `output` list entry is named. So this works:

```
library(shiny)

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Biomarker Comparison'),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = c('tabs'), 
                
                tabPanel('Plot 1 Options', selectInput('study', label = 'Study Type', 
                                                                  choices = c('EX')), 
                         uiOutput('Option1'), 
                         uiOutput('Option2'), 
                         uiOutput('Option3')
                ),
                tabPanel('Plot 2 Options', selectInput('studya', label = 'Study Type', 
                                                                choices = c('EX')), 
                         uiOutput('Option1a'), 
                         uiOutput('Option2a'), 
                         uiOutput('Option3a')
                )
    )
  ),
    mainPanel(imageOutput('plot')
  )
  )
))
s <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Option1 = renderUI({
    if (input$study == 'EX') {
      
      selectInput('differ', label='Patient ID', 
                  choices = c('013412-826-001-002','013412-840-001-001',
                              '013412-840-001-002',
                              '013412-840-001-003','013412-840-001-004'))
    }
  })
  output$plot <- renderImage({
    return(list(
      src = "./images/EXG.jpeg",
      contentType = "image/jpeg",
      alt = "Face"
    ))
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}
shinyApp(ui = u, server = s)
```

Yielding:
[image]

## Update:

I added a `deleteFile=FALSE` at the end to keep `renderImage` from deleting it every time it ran. Not sure why it wants to do this by default.

Comment: Any feedback  from the OP?